# Can a method refer to its object in a callback without bind()?

Tags: javascript, oop, bind

I was making a test case to show how 'bind' is necessary for a method to refer to its function in a callback.

But just when I thought I knew JS - the following code works fine - without requiring bind!

```
pretendThingConstructor = function (greeting) {
    this.greeting = greeting;
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log(this.greeting);
    };
}

var pretend_thing = new pretendThingConstructor('hello world');

pretend_thing.sayHello();

setTimeout(function() {  
    pretend_thing.sayHello()
}, 3000);
```

When I run it - via node, phantomjs, or another JS environment - it works. 'hello world' is printed twice.

I expected the second 'hello world' - the one ran after the timout - to fail, as 'this' would refer to the event, rather than the object. But it works. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` changes depending on how your *call* the function. If you specify a *base object*, it will refer to that instead:

```
pretend_thing.sayHello()
```

Here `pretend_thing` is that base object and therefore `this` still refers to that object. On the other hand, if you had:

```
var f = pretend_thing.sayHello;
f();
```

Here `this` should refer to `window` object instead.

You can confirm it by putting:

```
console.log (this instanceof pretendThingConstructor);
```

Inside your `sayHello` function. It will print `true` in both cases.

---

```
pretendThingConstructor = function (greeting) {
    this.greeting = greeting;
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log(this.greeting);
        console.log(this instanceof pretendThingConstructor);
    };
}

var pretend_thing = new pretendThingConstructor('hello world');
////////////////////////////

pretend_thing.sayHello();

setTimeout(function() {  
    pretend_thing.sayHello();
}, 3000);
```

will output:

```
true
true
```

whereas:

```
var f = pretend_thing.sayHello;
f();
```

outputs:

```
false
```

Answer (score 1):

In the scope of the function 'pretendThingConstructor',  'this' refers to the function itself. When the constructor is run (when you instantiate an object using the 'new' keyword), the sayHello method (which is an anonymous method) will be assigned to the property 'sayHello' on the instantiated object (in your case, pretend_thing).

Because you're calling the 'sayHello' method FROM an instance of the 'pretendThingConstructor' object (pretend_thing), 'this' refers to the object that you're calling the method from, not the context that you're executing in.

You can change the meaning of the 'this' keyword by using the .apply method:

```
function myHello(){
    this.greeting = 'Hello';
    this.method = function(){
         this.greeting
    }
}

function myGoodbye(){
    this.greeting = 'Goodbye';
    this.say = function(){
         console.log( this.greeting );
    }
}

var hello = new myHello();
var goodbye = new myGoodbye();

hello.say(); // Outputs 'Hello'
goodbye.say(); // Outputs 'Goodbye'

hello.say.apply( goodbye ); // Outputs 'Goodbye'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes in this case the this object of sayHello is pretend_thing because the function *knows* on which item it is called. The this only gets lost if you're trying to do this:

<-- language: lang-js -->

```
var say = pretend_thing.say_hello;
setTimeout(function () {
    say(); // this is window or null
}, 15)

// You can do something like
function doThings() {
    console.log(this.thing);
}

var test1 = { doThings: doThings, thing: 1 };
var test2 = { doThings: doThings, thing: 2 };

test1.doThings(); // <- 1
test2.doThings(); // <- 2
```

So the context depends on where the function is attached. But you can override this behavior with the bind-thing.